# How does Jest/Vitest do ".not." attributes without using parentheses? How could I replicate it?

Tags: javascript

Right now I'm required to do `validate.not().empty(...)` and it works fine to negate a "not empty" validation. But after looking at Vitest with the assertions of `expect.not.toBe(...)` that don't use parentheses, I'm left wondering how this would be coded. I tried a few things with proxies, getters and `addProperty` but haven't found a solution to replicate this setup.

Right now I just have this:

```
not() {
    this.is_not = true;
    return this;
}
```

Is there an easy way to do this or am I better of just using `.not().` instead of `.not.`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty):

```
Object.defineProperty(a, 'not', {
    get: function(){
        this.is_not=true;
        return this
    }
})
```

Note: It's really odd design to mutate `this` in a property getter. I'd *strongly recommend* to make a copy instead.

Answer (score 0):

mousetail's answer works, but just to give the answer the ES6 way, this is what I ended up using since it compiles to `Object.defineProperty`:

```
class Validation {
  errors: ValidationErrorItem[] = [];
  is_not = false;

  get not() {
    this.is_not = true;
    return this;
  }
  . . .
```